# If $f_n:\Omega\to\Omega$ are homeomorphisms of a planar domain $\Omega$ such that $f_n\to f$, $f_n^{-1}\to g$ in $L^1$, is $f=g^{-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, fluid-dynamics

In Marchioro and Pulvirenti's book *Mathematical Theory of Incompressible Nonviscous Fluids*, the proof of global well-posedness of the 2D Euler equation in a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ works by approximating the flow $\Phi^n_t(x)$ of the fluid given initial vorticity $\omega_0\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, and showing that $\Phi^n\to\Phi$ for some $\Phi$, with convergence in $L^\infty([0,T];L^1(\Omega))$, and similar arguments show convergence $(\Phi^n)^{-1}\to\tilde\Phi$ for some $\tilde\Phi$. Implicitly, the authors assume that $\Phi_t^{-1}=\tilde \Phi_t$ for all $t$, but I don't see why this must hold.

If it is of any use, I have found that the $\Phi^n$ and their inverses must all be incompressible flows, which are differentiable in time, and $C^{0,s}$ in space for some $s>0$.

Comment: May one assume that at least one of $\Phi$ and $\tilde \Phi$ is in $C^{0,s}$ too? Furthermore, may one assume that either the sequence $(\Phi_n)$ or the sequence $(\Phi_n ^{-1})$ has *bounded* Hölder constants?

Comment: Can you give a more precise reference? I couldn't find the step you mention.

Comment: @Dap: The reasoning seems to be spread across pages 69-71 but, indeed, does not look like what the OP is understanding of it.

Comment: @AlexM.: I take back my earlier statement -- in equation 3.39, the authors seem to implicitly assume that $\Phi_{-t}=\Phi_t^{-1}$ under the limit, and that $\Phi_t$ is volume-preserving, which is essentially the content of my question (though I misunderstood precisely where the authors were using this).

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine: I do not know what the earlier statement was, because I was away from the computer (did you post and then delete a comment?). Anyway, I still don't find clear how your question relates to the text.

Comment: @AlexM. In the second line of eq (3.39), the authors claim that $$\int_D f(x)\omega_0(\Phi_{-t}(x))\,dx=\int_D f(\Phi_t(x))\omega_0(x)\,dx$$ which implicitly assumes that $\Phi_{-t}$ and $\Phi_t$ are inverses, and both are volume-preserving transformations.

Comment: For further context, a similar claim to my question is precisely made at the top of page 316 of Majda and Bertozzi's book in a similar context, but where we have uniform convergence in $L^\infty$ as opposed to in $L^1$, which makes the argument much more straightforward.

Comment: I tried to answer the question from the title. Is it assumed that $f$ and $g$ also are homeomorphism of $D$? Otherwise the claim fails even in $\Bbb R$. For instance, let $D=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$ for each positive integer $n$. Then a sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges in $L^1$ to a function $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in [0,1]$ and a sequence $\{f_n^{-1}\}$ converges in $L^1$ to a function $g$ such that $g(x)=1$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. But neither $f$ not $g$ is a homeomorphism of $D$.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a domain? A closure of an open set? An open set?

Comment: By a domain, I mean an open set, whose closure is a compact manifold with boundary embedded in the plane (to be very precise), and I cannot assume in this context that $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms.